Concatenating Pandas dataframes into one GeoPandas dataframe
I am trying to concatenate three geodataframes with different CRSs. Before that I made sure I convert them to similar CRS (4326) as follows but still the concatenation is not working. What is wrong?
No= No.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:26191'})  # original CRS
Su=Su.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:26192'})  # original CRS
SaN= SaN.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:26194'})   # original CRS

# Create a function to compute the surface and convert back to GPS.
def  adjust_titre(df0:pd.DataFrame)-> pd.DataFrame:   

    geomap_unique=df0.copy()
    
    geomap_unique["area_km2"] = geomap_unique['geometry'].area/ 10**6   


    geomap_unique=geomap_unique.to_crs(4326)

    df_final=geomap_unique

    return df_final

# Apply the function
No_adjust=adjust_titre(No)

# check the CRSs are indeed converted

print('CRS after computing area',No_adjust.geometry.crs)

print('CRS after computing area',Su_adjust.geometry.crs)

print('CRS after computing area',SaN_adjust.geometry.crs)

The output shows that all geodataframes have similar CRSs.
CRS after computing area epsg:4326
CRS after computing area epsg:4326
CRS after computing area epsg:4326

Try the concatenation,
gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([No_adjust, Su_adjust, SaN_adjust], ignore_index=True), crs=4326)

I get the error:
f"Cannot determine common CRS for concatenation inputs, got {names}. "
   1415     "Use `to_crs()` to transform geometries to the same CRS before merging."
   1416 )



 ValueError: Cannot determine common CRS for concatenation inputs, got ['Merchich / Sahara Nord', 'Merchich / Nord Maroc', 'Merchich / Sud Maroc']. Use `to_crs()` to transform geometries to the same CRS before merging.
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...


Does gpd.pd.concat([No_adjust, Su_adjust, SaN_adjust]) work?

No unfortunately i get the same error as before. I just rechecked that the CRS is the same by doing this No_adjust.geometry.crs == Su_adjust.geometry.crs == SaN_adjust.geometry.crs   the output is True. I was if there is a way to compute the surface in GPS (in degree)

What does this do df0:pd.DataFrame?

df0:pd.DataFrame imposes a dataframe structure as input. It does not change anything, when I remove it. I still get the same CRS error.

Did you try using to_crs(4326, inplace=True) instead of creating a new object? Also, it could be a bug in the geopandas version, so I suggest trying changing that if this doesn't work.
